# jquery-UI dialog() crash js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Ive got the following problem. When i call

```
$("#dialog-1").dialog();
```

the javascript crashes i have the following files included

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

thats how my html div looks like

```
            <div id="dialog-1" title="Dialog Title goes here...">This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>
        <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

ive checked in fire bug all the file are include.

The error message :

> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: What is the version of jquery-ui? There could be compatablity issues between jQuery 1.10.2 and the jQuery UI version.

Comment: @Barry im using jquery-ui 1.11.2
the error message is "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function"

Comment: It is not a problem with the versions. I did a [check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLr7xLwL/) and they are compatible. Have you already tried another browser? Maybe one of the tags on the page is not closed and therefor not rendered/parsed correctly. Some browsers are more strict than others.

Comment: An alternative is to copy/paste the source code of the page in [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to check for inconsistencies.

Comment: @pitruskjw If the error says *"dialog is not a function"* that probably means jquery ui is not loaded. Check whether it is loaded under sources..

Comment: OK ive resolve it :). Jquery was declared twice